# How do I get rid of - Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, ecmascript-6

How can I get rid of this warning. I hate seeing it in the console. I feel I'm doing everything right but I keep getting this warning. This is what I'm doing:

```
      {reviews.map((review, i) => {
    return (
      <>
        <sl-details summary={`${review.name}`} key={i} open>
          <p>{review.review}</p>
        </sl-details>
        <br />
      </>
    );
  })}
```

I don't know if the stack is of any relevance but I'm using Nextjs and shoelace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't position your `key` on the **first node** within your map's callback.

> Fragments declared with the explicit <React.Fragment> syntax may have
> keys. A use case for this is mapping a collection to an array of
> fragments

Checkout the very last section of [that page](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html).

So your code should become:

```
{reviews.map((review, i) => {
    return (
      <React.Fragment key={i}>
        <sl-details summary={`${review.name}`} open>
          <p>{review.review}</p>
        </sl-details>
        <br />
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  })}
```

Comment: thanks! I have learnt something new today. Never realised

Comment: You’re welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

The `key={i}` should be put on the outer `<></>` elements, and for that to be possible, you need to convert them to full `<Fragment>` elements.

Updated code:

```
{reviews.map((review, i) =>
    <Fragment key={i}>
      <sl-details summary={`${review.name}`} open>
        <p>{review.review}</p>
      </sl-details>
      <br />
    </Fragment>
)}
```

PS I also shortened it to not use the unneeded `return`.

Comment: You're right. Thanks!